Ratio of limit when you can't use L'Hôpital's rule
Let $b_n$ be a sequence such that $b_n \to 1$. Let $c_n$ be a sequence such that $c_n \to 0$. Let $x_n$ be a sequence such that $x_n \to \infty$. Let $U$ and $a$ be a function such that
$$\frac{U(x_n(b_n+c_n)) - U(x_n)}{a(x_n)} \to \frac{1^\gamma - 1}{\gamma} = 0$$
for some $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$.
Clearly, $\frac{b_n^\gamma-1}{\gamma} \to 0$ also.
Then why does it follow that
$$\frac{[U(x_n(b_n+c_n)) - U(x_n)]\gamma}{a(x_n) (b_n^\gamma-1)} \to 1$$
?
I have tried to put it in more generality than in the text that I'm using. In the text, the relevant part is here:

Here, given a strictly increasing distribution function $F$, $U$ is the inverse of $\frac{1}{1-F}$ or equivalently $U(x) = F^{-1}(1-\frac{1}{x})$. The fundamental relation $C_\gamma$ refers to the assumption that for some $a(x)$,
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{U(xu)-U(x)}{a(x)} = \frac{u^\gamma-1}{\gamma}$$ for all $u>0$.
$v$ is a fixed real number.
Finally, $n \to \infty$, $k \to \infty$, but $\frac{k}{n} \to 0$  so $\frac{n}{k} \to \infty$.
Basically, I do not understand the first limit relation in the image.
Thank you

@Maxime I should have written $0$ there instead of $1$, thanks.
